# GET result placed into <div> using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Simple GET using AJAX and jQuery. Trying to place the resulting html into div below form. The DIV is not populating, what am I doing wrong?

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function myFunction()
        {
            var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
            $.get( "fetch-photographer.php?name="+name,(
                function( data ) {
                    $( "#responseArea" ).html( data );
                })
            );
        }
    );
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Enter a search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="responseArea"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What happens ? What is the error ?

Comment: The div does not have any result.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main problems:

---

You have defined `myFunction` in the scope of another function. It isn't a global, so you can't access it from your `onsubmit` function.

Make `myFunction` a global:

```
$(document).ready( // Remove this line
    function myFunction() {
        // ...
    }
); // Remove this line
```

---

You are running your JS when you submit the form.

1. The JavaScript sends the HTTP request
2. The form submits
3. The page goes away
4. A new page loads
5. There is no JS to handle the HTTP response

Add `return false` to the end of the `onsubmit` function.

```
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
```

Better yet, use a modern way to bind your event handlers:

```
<form id="form" method="post">

$("#form").on("submit", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // rest of your function
}
```

---

Note that you are failing to escape any special characters the user might type in. Don't create your query strings by hand if you are using jQuery, take advantage of its built-in functions for that: Pass the data as an object via the second argument to `$.get`.

```
$.get(
    "fetch-photographer.php",
    { name: document.forms["form"]["name"].value },
    function (data) {
        $("#responseArea").html(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried the suggestions, function to handle the GET is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, You are trying with submit action. so once the result came the page will get refreshed. So, you will not able to see the AJAX response replaced in your div.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
    var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
    $.get( "fetch-photographer.php?name="+name,(
        function( data ) {
            $( "#responseArea" ).html( data );
        })
    );
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Enter a search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="responseArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: same problem as above the function inside the get is not being called.

Comment: Use firebug to track, whether AJAX call is triggered or not. Also verify you are getting response from fetch-photographer.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare Javascript function inside the jquery ready function ...  I did it same thing using form submit event in jquery and remove extra pair bracket

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e){
            var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
            $.get( "fetch-photographer.php?name="+name,
                function( data ) {
                    $( "#responseArea" ).html( data );
                });
        });
    });
```

Comment: With this code, the `onsubmit` attribute in the `form` tag is not needed.

Comment: won't hit $( "#responseArea" ).html( data );